# UIView swipe gesture conflicts with tableview in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have more than 20 viewcontrollers in my project and added swipe gesture in global viewcontroller class.

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *rightSwipeGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(navigateToPreviousScreen:)];
rightSwipeGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = YES;
rightSwipeGesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:rightSwipeGesture];
```

And override all sub class

```
- (void)navigateToPreviousScreen:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender { 

[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];}
```

Now i got a problem (not exactly a problem), The some of the viewcontrollers has tableviews and that swipe is not work sometimes(also got some touch sensitive issue). Is there a way to solve it. I set cancelsTouchesInView = No but seems problem occurs.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to fix this by implementing & returning YES in the following `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` method in the parent class.

```
  - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
        return YES;
}
```

Comment: Ok Thanks. I have added the method in the parent class, it seems resolved the issues.

Comment: Ok. you should mark this answer as correct if this solves it.

Comment: sorry. now i did it.